Nested *ngFor in Angular v18.2.2
I am trying to make a simple contact book to work on my skills. I have it so that contacts can have many emails. My API endpoint for contacts is http://localhost:8080/contacts and my endpoint for emails is http://localhost:8080/contacts/{id}/emails. What I want to do is have a table that shows all of the contacts with their related emails in one column. What is the best approach to make this happen? I am worried I am approaching it the wrong way.
I tried to make a directive to run a function to get that data, but it doesn't seem to run.
This is my component.html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Emails</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let tempContact of contacts">
        <td>{{ tempContact.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ tempContact.lastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ tempContact.company }}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let tempEmail of emails" (runFunc)="test(tempContact.id)">{{ tempEmail.id }}</td>
    </tr> 
</table>

This is my custom.directive.ts
  @Output() runFunc: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.runFunc.emit('dummy');
  }

This is my component.ts
  test(id: number): void {
    this.contactService.getEmailsById(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.emails = data;
    })
  }

this is my contact.service.ts
  getEmailsById(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<GetResponseEmails>(this.baseUrl + this.contactsEndpoint + `/${id}` + this.emailsEndpoint)
      .pipe(map((response) => response._embedded.emails))
  }


Not recommend for your approach as you will call multiple API calls based on the number of contacts. This results in your API requires to handle multiple calls concurrently for the fetching associated email operations. Instead, make your Contacts API in the backend that allows you to return the contacts with their associated emails.

This approach resembles ng-init of AngularJS, but it's better to fetch all the data in a single go using observable streams leveraging RxJs operators.

You have to use RxJs to perform the API calls in sequence. First we fetch the user details, then we perform the API for contacts, using the RxJs operator switchMap which switches from the first API to the second API, all in one observable stream. This is generally used for nested APIs, where the second API depends on the first API details.
getuserDetails(id: number) { 
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + this.contactsEndpoint).pipe(map((response) => response._embedded.user));
}

getEmailsById(id: number) { 
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + this.contactsEndpoint + /${id} + this.emailsEndpoint).pipe(map((response) => response._embedded.emails));
}

getUserDetailsAll(userId: number) {
    return this.getuserDetails(userId).pipe(
        switchMap((userDetails: any) => {
            return this.getEmailsById(userDetails.id).pipe(
                tap((emails) => {
                    userDetails.emails = emails;
                })
            )
        })
    );
}

On your component TS, it will look like:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactService.getUserDetailsAll(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data;
    })
}

On your component HTML we use the email array inside the users array.
Since you are using Angular18 try using the new control flow syntax instead of the old one.
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Emails</th>
    </tr>
    @for(tempContact of contacts; track $index) {
        <tr>
            <td>{{ tempContact.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ tempContact.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ tempContact.company }}</td>

            @for(tempEmail of tempContact.emails; track $index) {
                <td>{{ tempEmail }}</td>
            }
        </tr> 
    }
</table>


That makes perfect sense! Thank you, I’ll let you know how it works out when I get back to it.

You may want to use a combination of concatMap and from so that you can create HTTP requests concurrently while immediately reflecting the responses individually as they come back to the client. This approach is useful compared to Promise.all or forkJoin, which wait for all requests to complete before updating the state.
Here is a pseudo-code example of your main component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { signal } from '@angular/core';
import { concatMap, from, map } from 'rxjs';

interface Contact {
  id: number;
  company: string;
  emails?: string[];
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
    @for (contact of contacts(); track $index) {
      <td>{{ contact.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.company }}</td>
      @for (email of contact.emails; track $index) {
        <td>{{ email }}</td>
      }
    }
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  contacts = signal<Contact[]>([]);

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {
    this.fetchEmailsForAllContacts();
  }

  private fetchEmailsForAllContacts(): void {
    from(this.contacts()).pipe(
      concatMap(contact =>
        this.contactService.getEmailsById(contact.id).pipe(
          map((emails: Contact['emails']) => ({ ...contact, emails: emails || [] }))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(updatedContact => {
      this.contacts.update(contacts => {
        return contacts.map(contact =>
          contact.id === updatedContact.id ? updatedContact : contact
        );
      });
    });
  }
}

Given a ContactService with a method:
getEmailsById(id: number) {
  return this.http.get<Contact['emails']>('get-contact-emails/' + id).pipe(take(1));
}

Additional notes:

The example utilizes the new @for syntax introduced in Angular 18. You should replace your *ngFor statements
The example provided does not include error handling. Make sure to add catch.

